# shared_ptr ошибка при линковке c++

Tags: c++, g++, clang

[pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/TMnaeMtj) - исходный код заголовочного файла с реализацией shared_ptr.

[pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/3SUPVMVX) - CPP файл в котором ничего экстраординарного.

При компиляции выдает следующее:
[pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/LWABKBzS)

Помогите пожалуйста, не могу понять где ошибки. Спасибо!

Comment: Код на SO принято приводить прямо в вопросе.

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, ваш компилятор знает, что такое С++11, но по умолчанию работает в до-С++11 режиме. В результате любые попытки использования свойств С++11 распознаются, но приводят к предупреждениям. Переведите компилятор в режим С++11 или выше.

Во-вторых, вы сделали лишь *объявление* статического члена `setOfPointers`, не не сделали его *определения*. О чем вам компилятор сказал открытым текстом ("...but no definition is available"). В С++14 и ранее определение должно делаться явно и располагаться за пределами класса. В силу "навороченности" типа `setOfPointers` это определение тоже будет довольно "навороченным"

```
template<typename T> 
std::vector< typename shared_ptr<T>::template storage<T> > shared_ptr<T>::setOfPointers;
```

Так как это шаблонное определение, располагаться оно должно в заголовочном файле.

(По вашему коду, однако, не ясно, зачем внутренний тип `storage` тоже сделан самостоятельным шаблоном со своим независимым параметром. Зачем?)

Если ваш компилятор поддерживает С++17, то вы можете избавиться от необходимости делать это определение явно, просто добавив ключевое слово `inline` в объявление статического члена класса

```
static inline std::vector< storage<T> > setOfPointers;
```